# Javascript - Replacing any instance of character in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

Take the following string:

```
Lodder
```

What I'm trying to do is, ensure the above is the result of any alternatives that are written on `keypress`. Possible alternatives could be something like:

> Lo**a**der 
>   Lo **[a]** der 
>  
>   Lo **.a** der

The alternatives are always based on the letter `a` replacing the first `d` in the string

The code I've written so far:

```
$('#element').keyup(function(e) {

    var Lodder = this.value.replace(/Loader|Lo4der/g, 'Lodder');

    if (Lodder != this.value)
    {
        this.value = Lodder;
    }

});
```

As you can see, it only replaces exact alternatives, however I'm trying to make it more dynamic by detecting more advanced alternatives.

Is there a more or less simple, but, robust solution to this?

If so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: *Note:* Sorry if I haven't explained the above too well. Having an extremely "off" day

Comment: `value.replace(/\bLo.*?der\b/g, 'Lodder');`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - You're a star. Thank you. Please feel free to write your comment as a proper answer so I can accept it

Comment: @Lodder The replacement is the easy part. However, replacing the value of an input while the user is typing into it offsets the cursor and therefore ruins the user experience. Your main concern should be with retrieving and maintaining cursor position across the operation.

Comment: @Tomalak - You make a good point. I will change the event to `$('.submit').on('click', function ...`

Comment: Since there is more than one way to submit a form (i.e. pressing Enter in the last field can do it, or calling the submit method), make that `$("#theForm").on("submit", function() { ... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*?` to match any number of characters non-greedily.

```
value.replace(/\bLo.*?der\b/g, 'Lodder');
```

`\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character (*vice-versa*).